# What is the manifold associated with the quotient space $SU(n)/SO(n)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, quotient-spaces, homogeneous-spaces

I'm a physicist studying control problems in quantum theory, and one of the ways to understand this is to consider coset spaces and Lie groups. What I am curious about are the manifolds associated with various quotient groups, and I am interested in two specific cases.

The first arises from a Cartan decomposition of a Lie algebra $\cal{L}$ into $\cal{L} = \cal{K} + \cal{P}$, where $\cal{P} = \cal{K}^{\perp}$. If the Lie algebra is $su(n)$ we can perform a Cartan decomposition $su(n) = so(n) \oplus {\cal{I}}$ where ${\cal{I}}$ is the vector space in $su(n)$ of purely imaginary matrices. Understanding the associated control problem involves studying the quotient space $e^{\cal{L}}/e^{\cal{K}}$.

This means I need to understand the topology of the quotient space $G/K$, where $G = SU(n)$ and $K=SO(n)$.

**Question 1**: I know $SU(n)/SO(n)$ should be a differentiable manifold of dimension $\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)-1$, but what exactly is it? A hypersphere? A hypertorus? As an example, I know the answer for $n=2$: the quotient space $SU(2)/SO(2)$ is isomorphic to the two-sphere $S^2$. But I can't find the answer for $n>2$.

**Question 2**: Exactly the same as above, but now I don't have a Cartan decomposition and the quotient group manifold I need to find is given by $SU(n)/U(1)$.

Any suggestions gratefully accepted. Since I'm new to this, and I'm a physicist and not a mathematician, it's possible my questions don't even make sense, in which case I would appreciate anyone pointing out my misconceptions!

Comment: May be relevant : *Homotopy groups of homogeneous space SU(n)/SO(n)*, Hideyuki Kachi.

Comment: $SU(n)/U(1)$ is the projectivisation of $SU(n)$ and is usually denoted by $PSU(n)$.

Comment: In general $SU(n)/SO(n)$ doesn't have an alternative description, it is just that smooth manifold. For $n = 3$, it often goes by the name 'Wu manifold'.

Comment: For $n\geq 3$, the manifold has $H^3(SU(n)/SO(n))$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.  That precludes it from being diffeomorphic to any of the "usual" spaces.  By the way, I think that @Didier meant $U(n)/U(1)$ instead of $SU(n)/U(1)$.  The space $U(n)$ has a canonical copy of $U(1)$ given by the center, and indeed, $U(n)/U(1) = PSU(n)$.  On the other hand, $SU(n)$ has many copies of $U(1)$, but none are canonical, and $SU(n)/U(1)\neq PSU(n)$ for any of them (look at $\pi_1$).

Comment: As a side remark, $U(n)/O(n)$ can be identified as the space of Lagrangian subspace in $\mathbb R^{2n}$ (The Lagrangian Grassmannian). I guess one has a similar description of $SU(n)/SO(n)$, in terms of some subset of the Grassmannians.

Comment: Many thanks everybody! I will pick my way through your suggestions, learning as I go :-)

Comment: Sorry, one more thing: In light of your answers, I have a final question. I'm not familiar with stackexchange etiquette, so I'm not sure whether to post a new question or carry on here, but I'll try here first. The reason I wanted to know about the manifold is that I wanted to know the metric in order find the diameter of the manifold (i.e. the two points furthest apart). I know that for a Lie group I can use Killing form on the associated Lie algebra to get a metric. Any suggestions on how to find the (a?) metric for these quotient groups?

Comment: @mollusc you can take an isom. of the underlying vector spaces $\mathfrak{su}(n) \simeq \mathfrak{so}(n) \oplus \mathfrak{m}$ where $\mathfrak{m}$ is the vector space $\mathfrak{su}(n)/\mathfrak{so}(n)$, which is the tangent space to $SU(n)/SO(n)$ at the identity coset $eSO(n)$. Then for a pair of tangent vectors $X,Y$ on the quotient manifold at $gSO(n)$, translate them back to $eSO(n)$ using the $SU(n)$-action, and then apply the (negative of the) Killing form of $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ to the vectors $(0,g^{-1}X)$, $(0,g^{-1}Y)$. This uses the _reductive_ property of the homogeneous space